# VBA coding to retrieve data from database using predetermined dates

Tags: database, vba

I am very new to VBA coding and tried to find the code for a specific task. I have a database ("Sanitation") with a date column. The database is on the sheet "Sanitation Schedule". I have created a form to set the required start and end dates and copy them on cell A2 (start date) and A3 (end date) of sheet "Sanitation Form". I want to select the rows of my database between the predetermined start and end dates, copy the rows to an other sheet "Sanitation Form". It sounds probably very basic coding but it is out of my knowledge. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .Find

```
Dim StartDate As Date
StartDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sanitation Form").Range("A2").value
Dim EndDate As Date
EndDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sanitation Form").Range("A3").value

Startrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sanitation").Cells.Find(Format(StartDate, "d-mmm-yy"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sanitation").Range("A1"), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlNext, False, False).Row
Endrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sanitation").Cells.Find(Format(EndDate, "d-mmm-yy"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sanitation").Range("A1"), xlValues, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlNext, False, False).Row
```

And then copy the rows in between

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Sorry to ask another question. How can I set the object variable? I receive the run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Can you paste your code?

Comment: Thank you again for your support. The error message is as follow: Run-Time error 91 (Object variable or  With block variable not set)

Comment: This is probably because of date formatting. Where it says "Find(Format(StartDate, "d-mmm-yy")", change the format to whatever you are using

Comment: If this answered your question, you can mark the question as answered

Comment: Click the tick sign to the left of my answer. [Site FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)